# How to do a session control with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have to perform a login with javascript in a web-service (mede with cake php), if i use common request (non ajax) everything is fine but when i use the bellow code after login on countUpdates i get a 403 forbidden. After login on countUpdates ajax call sends a cake session cookie different from other calls, this is right or have a trick to use on ajax?

This is my javacript code:

```
 function Api() {
        }

        Api.login = function(callback)
        {
            $.post("api/login/{0}?no-cache={1}".format(Api.udid, Math.random()), null, function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }, 'json');
        };

        Api.logout = function(callback)
        {
            $.post("api/logout/?no-cache={0}".format(Math.random()), null, function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }, 'json');
        };

        Api.countUpdates = function(last_update, callback)
        {
            $.post("api/countUpdates/{0}?no-cache={1}".format(last_update, Math.random()), null, function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }, 'json');
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            Api.udid = "2b6f0cc904d137be2e1730235f5664094b831186";

            Api.logout(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            });

            Api.login(function(response)
            {
                if (response.result)
                {
                    Api.countUpdates(0, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }

            });


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved im sorry its my fault:

Solution:

```
Api.logout(function(response)
                {
                    Api.login(function(response)
                    {
                        if (response.result)
                        {
                            Api.countUpdates(0, function(response) {
                                console.log(response);



                            });
                        }

                    });

                });
```